# How can I change the IP address of a running switch (HP 2510)?

Tags: switch, switching, hp, hp-procurve, ip-address

The switch is running at a remote location and is connected to a network with the IP address `10.10.10.10`. How can I change the IP address to `10.10.10.11` via telnet? The switch has to stay reachable and must not get an IP address via DHCP.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

It can be problematic to change an address remotely. The best option is to do it in person from the directly attached console. To move the switch to a different subnet, that is indeed what is required. In your case, it's still in the same subnet with the same gateway, so you can just telnet in and change it. The instant the command is entered, your telnet session will stop, but you should be able to telnet to the new address and continue. (save the config, etc.)

When moving to a different subnet, the gateway has to be changed as well. You'll lose contact the instant either the gateway or address are changed. And the address has to change first. If you have machines in both networks, and changing the address of the switch will not otherwise break the network, then logging in to each network allows you a *local* path (not through a gateway) to the switch in either subnet. Change the address, go to the machine in the other network and continue your work.

If you have console (out-of-band) access, none of this mess is required.

Answer (score 3):

You normally would just overwrite it with e. g.:

```
vlan 1 ip address 10.10.10.11/8
```

But if you stay on the same subnet, the switch will complain:

```
The IP address (or subnet) 10.10.10.11/8 already exists.
```

If this is the case (you want to stay in the same subnet and just change the IP address inside this subnet), then you'll have to delete the previous IP address first. But then you'll will loose your remote connectivity, if you cannot reach your switch through another subnet. So that's probably not an option.

A working solution is to use the HP menu to change the IP address instead of using bare configuration commands. Perform the following steps:

1. Open the interactive HP menu with the command `menu`.
2. Select option `2. Switch Configuration...`.
3. Select option `4. IP Configuration`.
4. Select the action `Edit`.
5. Edit your IP address according to your needs and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.
6. Select the action `Save`.

You'll loose your connection immediately, but you'll also be able to immediately reconnect to the new IP address.

Answer (score 2):

If you have more than one VLAN running (lets say 10 with 10.10.10.10 and 20 ) on the switch you could give the switch an IP address in another VLAN Interface (i. e. VLAN 20 with 20.20.20.20); check if you could connect to it (20.20.20.20) and if it is so you can change the IP address (10.10.10.10) while connected via telnet to the other VLAN interface (20.20.20.20) on the switch.

Please think of it and check (2nd VLAN will be routed to your location and so on) if this will be a oppertunity for you befor doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the reload command to issue a delayed reload to the switch. Then make your change and see if it worked. If you messed up, the switch will reboot with the old configuration intact, enabling you to try again until you get it right.

https://grumpytechie.net/2015/03/06/using-the-reload-command-with-hp-switches-hp-networking-series-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

Your production setup  can be impacted, if you wants to change ip address of switch in production hours . And you might loss access to switch as well.

If switch is connected in HA having both active and passive switch or active -active switch then ,  there is a possibility to change ip address of switch in production hours . Remove HA cable between switch make them independent devices and shift all work load on any one of switch , on remaining switch you can change ip address .

If both switches are not in HA . Then schedule activity post production hours . And take switch console access and processed with activity .